# Getting Textbox value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to get the value of the textbox in a javascript, but its not working. Given below is the code of my test page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="test3.aspx.vb" Inherits="test3" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
<script language="javascript">

    function GetAlert() {

        var TestVar = document.getElementById('txt_model_code').value;
        alert(TestVar);

    }

</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_model_code" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox><br /><br />

<input type="button" value="db Function" onclick="GetAlert()" /><br />
</asp:Content>
```

So where am i going wrong?? How to get the text entered in the textbox in the javascript???

Comment: do this: `var TestVar = document.getElementById('<%= txt_model_code.ClientID %>').value;`

Comment: @deostroll thanks it worked.. Now what to do if i want to show that value in another textbox

Comment: document.getElementById('<%= anothertextboxid.ClientID %>').value=TestVar

Comment: as it is asp.net control, you can not get the value using getElementById(). because asp.net controls are converted to html controls and "id" changes on the browser. for more details refer: http://coding-issues.blogspot.in/2013/10/get-aspnet-textbox-label-value-javascript.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use

```
document.getElementById('<%= txt_model_code.ClientID %>')
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('txt_model_code')`
```

Also you can  use `onClientClick` instead of `onClick`.

Comment: when i use the function in text_model_code onTextChange, it's saying the function is not part of my aspx file.. Why??? <asp:TextBox ID="txt_model_code" runat="server" OnTextChanged="GetModelPageMethod()">

Comment: I think you need to use this in onChange="GetModelPageMethod();"

Answer (score 7):

This is because ASP.NET it changing the Id of your textbox, if you run your page, and do a view source, you will see the text box id is something like

`ctl00_ContentColumn_txt_model_code`

There are a few ways round this:

Use the actual control name:

`var TestVar = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentColumn_txt_model_code').value;`

use the ClientID property within ASP script tags

`document.getElementById('<%= txt_model_code.ClientID %>').value;`

Or if you are running .NET 4 you can use the new ClientIdMode property, see this link for more details.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx[1](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Since you have master page and your control is in content place holder, Your control id will be generated different in client side. you need to do like...

```
var TestVar = document.getElementById('<%= txt_model_code.ClientID %>').value;
```

Javascript runs on client side and to get value you have to provide client id of your control

Answer (score 1):

The ID you are trying is an serverside.

That is going to render in the browser differently.

try to get the ID by watching the html in the Browser.

var TestVar = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentColumn_txt_model_code').value;

this may works.

Or do that ClientID method. That also works but ultimately the browser will get the same thing what i had written.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
 public void Page_Load(object Sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        double rad=0.0;
        TextBox1.Attributes.Add("Visible", "False");
        if (TextBox1.Text != "") 
        rad = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text);    
        Button1.Attributes.Add("OnClick","alert("+ rad +")");
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Diameter" 
            style="z-index: 1; left: 133px; top: 181px; position: absolute" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Visible="True" Text="" runat="server" 
            AutoPostBack="true" 
            style="z-index: 1; left: 134px; top: 133px; position: absolute" ></asp:TextBox>
```

use the help of this, hope it will be usefull

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function MyFunction() {
                var FNumber = Number(document.getElementById('txtFirstNumber').value);
                var SNumber = Number(document.getElementById("txtSecondNumber").value);
                var Sum = FNumber + SNumber;
                alert(Sum);
            }

        </script>

        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td>FirstNaumber</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SecondNumber</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSecondNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="MyFunction()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```