# JavaScript function giving Uncaught reference error while getting the value of text box

Tags: javascript

I am trying make *textbox* blank and set focus on it using Java Script.
I used following            code for that

```
document.getElementById("textmob")="";
document.getElementById("textmob").focus;
```

But I get following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid leftend side assignment;
```

My Html Code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="mob" runat="server" CssClass="text" AutoPostBack="True" onchange = "validateMob(this)" ></asp:TextBox>
```

My validation function

```
 function validateMob(txtmob)

          {
            debugger;
            var rx = /^\d{10}$/;

           if (!txtmob.value.match(rx)) {
               alert('Invalid Mobile No');
               // document.getElementById("mob") = "";
              document.getElementById("mob").focus();
            }
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to use `.value` and `()` in `foucus()`

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("textmob").value = "";
document.getElementById("textmob").focus();
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FuF3Q/1/)

Comment: Is it Working in .net aspx textbox control.

Comment: @ashishkumar, please post your html also.

Comment: I made textbox autopostback property true

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="mob" runat="server" CssClass="text" AutoPostBack="True"  onchange = "validateMob(this)" ></asp:TextBox>

Comment: @ashishkumar, and how does that validate function look like? (post in your question)

Comment: @ashishkumar, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039544/getting-textbox-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can't just set it to "".

```
document.getElementById('textmob')
```

gives you the element itself.

In order to set the content of the element to "",

use .value.

```
document.getElementById("textmob").value="";
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives uncaughtTypeError: can not set property value to null

Answer (score 2):

This is invalid assignment:

```
document.getElementById("textmob")="";
```

You are trying to assign a string object to a JavaScript element. I guess `.value` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a minor mistake in your syntax it should be like that

```
document.getElementById("textmob").value="";
document.getElementById("textmob").focus();
```

check complete example

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function my()
{
        document.getElementById("textmob").value="";
        document.getElementById("textmob").focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="k" type="text">
<input id="textmob" type="text">

<button onclick="my()" id="b" value="Click ME">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i call javascript function on onchange event of text box

Comment: do you want to call that function on every keypress event in that textbox or when user has entered all the text?

Comment: onlost focus of textbox

Comment: Try onblur function   <input id="k" type="text" onblur="lost()">

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 document.getElementById("textmob").focus(function() {
      *do what you like with text field*;
    });
```