# Get value of ASP.NET Webform TextBox using JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webforms, controls

I have an asp control for a textbox and a script that's trying to get the value from the textbox but it wont fire the alert:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailList" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnCopyAll").click(function () {
            alert(document.getElementById('#txtEmailList').value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried:

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%txtEmailList.ClientID%>'));
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039544/getting-textbox-value-in-javascript) answer, but it did not work.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Try this alert($("#txtEmailList").val());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert(document.getElementById('#txtEmailList').value);
```

Should be:

```
alert(document.getElementById('txtEmailList').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to fetch the contents of the list using the `val()` method. `$("#txtEmailList")` selects the list:

```
alert($("#txtEmailList").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt

> alert(document.getElementById('#txtEmailList').value);

failed because you are using '#'. When using `getElementById` you just need the id without '#' so you could try

> `alert(document.getElementById('txtEmailList').value);`

Your second attempt

> alert(document.getElementById('<%txtEmailList.ClientID%>'));

failed because you have not used `.value`, so you could try

> `alert(document.getElementById('<%=txtEmailList.ClientID%>').value);`

Let me know how it goes.