# Cannot retrieve ASP.Net Textbox value in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've got an ASP.Net `TextBox` that I want to pass it's text value to a JavaScript function. I've tried several different methods, including the one at this answer, [Getting Textbox value in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039544/getting-textbox-value-in-javascript) but my value is always returned as `undefined`. These textboxes are part of an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` but I have tried this outside of the panel, and receive the same error.

This is my current code setup:

**ASP.Net**

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
    CssClass="login-boxes" TextMode="Email" MaxLength="255" ValidationGroup="rPage1" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
    CssClass="login-boxes" ValidationGroup="rPage1" />

<asp:Button ID="btnAdvance" runat="server" CssClass="login-buttons reg-btn-show" 
    OnClientClick="testFunction()" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Advance" 
    OnClick="btnAdvance_Click" ValidationGroup="rPage1" />
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var box1 = document.getElementById('<%= txtTest.ClientID %>').value;
var box2 = document.getElementById('<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>');
        
function testFunction() {
    box2.value = box1;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve, is if I type "Hello" into `txtTest` and click `btnAdvance`, it should populate `txtEmail` with "Hello". How can I achieve this?

Comment: `box1` will be set at the beginning and it won't update. So when you click `btnAdvance` it will not have updated value of `txtTest`. Try moving those `box1` & `box2` inside `testFunction`. It should work.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what the issue was. That oversight had me going for hours. If you want to submit as an answer, I'll accept, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box1` will be set at the beginning and it won't update. So when you click `btnAdvance` it will not have updated value of `txtTest`. Try moving those `box1` & `box2` inside `testFunction`. It should work.

```
function testFunction() {
    var box1 = document.getElementById('<%= txtTest.ClientID %>').value;
    var box2 = document.getElementById('<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>');
    box2.value = box1;
}
```